# Same input to Multiple variables in C directly

Tags: c

I want to create 5 variables whose value will be user inputted and all variable will have the **same value**, is there a way to directly assign values to all the 5 variables from scanf() instead of the regular way

```
int var1, var2, var3, var4, var5;
scanf("%d", &var1);
var2 = var3 = var4 = var5 = var1;
```

Comment: anatolyg's answer demonstrates why you should not tag a question with `c` and `c++` (unless you're asking about using `c` and `c++` in a program). I removed the `c++` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to directly assign values to all the 5 variables from scanf() instead of the regular way

No there isn't.  You have to assign to each of the variables where you want to copy the value, just like in your current code.

I'm not sure what the rest of your code is like, but often when you have several variables and want to perform some common operation on them, what you really need is an array and a loop.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can make references to the first variable:

```
int var1, &var2 = var1, &var3 = var1, &var4 = var1, &var5 = var1;
scanf("%d", &var1);
printf("%d\n", var2);
```

But this is pointless. If you want just one value, use just one variable.